# performance tuning maximo anywhere 7.5.2.0

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am working on the Maximo anywhere 7.5.2.0 version. I could seen lot of log trace on console while login successful. This always taken some time for downloading data.

I wanted to be tuning the performance.

And also wanted to be stoped the log trace while production. Can I do the code optimazation for performace tuning. If yes, Kindly suggest where I can do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the logLevel="0" in the app.xml it will disable logging.  In future releases, we've done a better job of disabling the logging even more at this lower log level.  The latest iFix for 7521 should have this fix.